# VBA Excel Won't Change Cell to the Right Color

Tags: vba, excel

I am new with using VBA macros in excel, and I am trying to change the background color of a cell based on the condition that another cell is not empty. I thought I had it figured out, but I must be doing something wrong, because no matter what color I specify the 'Interior.Color' to change to, it turns the cell an ugly blue color. Here's the code:

```
Sub Hello()
    MsgBox ("Hello, world!")

    Dim shSource As Worksheet
    Dim shDest As Worksheet

    Set shSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Box Channel Tracking")
    Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Box Channel Schematic")

    If shSource.Range("C176").Value <> "" Then
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid   
    Else
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Color = Red
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What version of excel are you using?

Comment: Are you using any conditional formattings????

Comment: Maybe they're overriding you VBA code. VBA does the right thing, then your conditional formatting goes there and blow it up.

Comment: And....are you `running` that code each time you change values of the cell in shSource? Or did you put it in some `SheetUpdate`event?

Answer (score 3):

You've got to use either the color's index or the appropriate RGB value. Change the first line of the `else` branch to:

```
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Full code sample:

```
Sub Hello() 
    MsgBox ("Hello, world!")

    Dim shSource As Worksheet
    Dim shDest As Worksheet

    Set shSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Box Channel Tracking")
    Set shDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Box Channel Schematic")

    If shSource.Range("C176").Value <> "" Then
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    Else
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) '<-modified
        shDest.Range("E8").Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I pasted my latest revision, I've used what you show there, RGB(255,0,0) as well as ColorIndex = 4, and tried several different colors and it always gives me a dark greenish blue.

Comment: Difficult to diagnose the problem without the actual code you're using right now.

Comment: I just have tried different colors to see if anything changes, but nothing does.

Comment: You haven't done anything to change the default palette colours, have you? You may want to put a `ActiveWorkbook.ResetColors` line in to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)=red BUT    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0,255)=blue  Do you get blue even when you have C175<>"" or is that correct at least?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the color palette for excel has not been changed
Depending upon your version you can reset it to a standard palette

in 2003 Tools>Options>Color
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288412 describes how to do this also

Or in a later version you may have a custom theme applied that is causing issues